# How to get the list of perforce depots that have no changelist?

Tags: perforce

Is it possible to get the list of depots (name of the depot) that have no changelist created along with their creation date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `p4 changes` against each depot, and print the name/time of each that has no results.

Here's a quick example using P4Python:

```
from datetime import datetime
from P4 import P4

with P4().connect() as p4:
    for d in p4.run_depots():
        depot = d['name']
        if not p4.run_changes("-m1", f"//{depot}/..."):
            print(depot, datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d['time'])))
```

When I run this script against my own local server it lists all the depots I've made that don't have any changelists in them:

```
Sprocket 2019-07-25 00:02:31
Widget 2019-07-24 23:45:04
repo 2020-04-28 09:53:13
spec 2022-02-08 08:23:23
```

compared to the full list of depots from `p4 depots`:

```
Depot Sprocket 2019/07/25 stream 1 Sprocket/... 'Created by Samwise. '
Depot Widget 2019/07/24 stream 1 Widget/... 'Created by Samwise. '
Depot collaborators 2020/07/12 stream 1 collaborators/... 'Created by Samwise. '
Depot depot 2019/09/22 local depot/... 'Created by Samwise. '
Depot repo 2020/04/28 local repo/... 'Created by Samwise. '
Depot spec 2022/02/08 spec .p4s spec/... 'Created by Samwise. '
Depot stream 2017/11/02 stream stream/... ''
```

Note that the `time` on the depot is the *modification* time; the depot spec doesn't maintain the original *creation* time.  However, it's likely that if no changelists have ever been submitted into a depot, the depot spec itself hasn't been modified since its creation either.

Comment: @Sanwise,   i get this error while passing one of the Deport name in the variable {depot = d['XYZ']}
**File "./LASTACCESSED.py", line 9
    if not p4.run_changes("-m1", f"//{depot}/..."):
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: [abc@instance-01 ~]$ cat LASTACCESSED.py  
#!/usr/bin/python  
from datetime import datetime  
from P4 import P4  
with P4().connect() as p4:  
    for d in p4.run_depots():  
        depot = d['name']  
        if not p4.run_changes("-m1", f"//{depot}/..."):  
            print(depot, datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d['time'])))  
---
[abc@instance-01-01 ~]$ ./LASTACCESSED.py  
  File "./LASTACCESSED.py", line 9  
    if not p4.run_changes("-m1", f"//{depot}/..."):                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  
---
When i used as is, it still same.

Comment: I see a reason because when i run the simple, p4 changes the output does not give me the time, however it give the date    
**Change 213306 on 2018/11/22 by**

Comment: Maybe you have a really old version of Python…?

Comment: I have python ***Python 2.7.5* . Will it work with your script ?

Comment: Oh yeah no, that's not even considered "Python" any more.  :)  Install Python 3.

Comment: You might be able to make the script work with Python 2 by changing `f"//{depot}/..."` to `"//" + depot + "/..."`, but it's been so long since I've used Python 2 I'm not sure if there are other syntactic incompatibilities.  Better to just upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Sam, One quick question.
Will this script only show me the depots I've created that don't have any changelists, or will it show me all depots on Server?

Comment: Only the ones that don't have changelists.  That's why it runs the `p4 changes` command on each depot to see if there are any changelists in that depot.  If you just wanted all the depots, you could just run `p4 depots` instead of running this script.