# List of most recently updated depots in Perforce

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to filter the most recently updated depots in Perforce server? I want to see only the depots that have updated after March 10th 2023.

Comment: By "updated" do you mean depots where the actual depot spec has been updated after that point, or depots where files have been submitted after that point?

Comment: I mean the files that have been submitted. Basically i want to identify the depots which are in use. Because we have lots of depots stored locally and consuming lot of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [How to get the list of perforce depots that have no changelist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72855128/how-to-get-the-list-of-perforce-depots-that-have-no-changelist) and the same script with two minor modifications (only look for changes after 2023/03/10, and report depots that *do* have changes rather than depots that *don't*) will do the job:

```
from P4 import P4

with P4().connect() as p4:
    for d in p4.run_depots():
        depot = d['name']
        if p4.run_changes("-m1", f"//{depot}/...@2023/03/10,@now"):
            print(depot)
```